# Double slash in path for downloaded modules

Tags: drush

When I download a module via Drush, the path contain two consecutive slashes like in /home/www/example/sited8//modules/contrib/key_value.

In *admin/config/media/file-system*, no extra slash is shown.

Perhaps it could be set in another part of the website.

Could it be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an artifact of how Drush [builds the path](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.x/commands/pm/download.pm.inc#L196). It looks at your Drupal project dir, and where it's placing the the project download, then appends it together without concern for a trailing slash in the Drupal project dir. It has nothing to do with your Drupal project file settings

Is it bug? Perhaps if you consider it a UX problem. As far as [POSIX is concerned](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271), the double slash is treated as one so it shouldn't matter in terms of referencing the directory. Whatever the case, `drush pm-download` is [deprecated in later versions](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/pm/pm:download/).

Comment: Thanks to explain, I didn't encounter issues despite this double slash. What is the new command for pml with Drush 8 so ?

Comment: There is no equivalent with Drush 9 alone. Drush 9 is giving a users a shove toward composer-driven projects where `composer require drupal/project_slug` would be the Drush 8 equivalent of `drush pm-download project_slug`.